# Design pattern for mapping database in Data Access Layer [C#]

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mapping, data-access-layer, business-layer

I work on my Data Access Layer where I use data mapper pattern. My actual structure of code is for example:

```
public class Person {
    public int Age
    public string FirstName
    public string LastName
    public List<Address> Addresses
    ...
}

public class PersonMapper {
    public Person GetPersonById(int id)
    public List<Person> GetAll()
    public bool UpdatePerson(Person person)
    ...
}
```

I have so many classes which are corresponding for database table with same name.

My questions are:

1. Is my approach right? When I mapped all tables, I will use it in the domain layer.
2. In Mapper classes I use methods which are working only with tables which are same name as these classes. (`Person` class -> Persons db table, `Order` class -> Orders db table, etc.) But what is the best way to map advanced selects from database, which will be contains joins to more tables. For example I want select `Person` with all his `Orders.` Should I create domain model for Person which will be contains property `List<Orders>`and use `PersonMapper` and next `OrderMapper`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's called a mapper. To me personally it's a repository. And if I could, I'd use entity framework which does all that for me.

Comment: EF I could not use ... why repository?

Comment: @DenisStephanov: In `DataAccessLayer` world, your `PersonMapper` class is generally called `PersonRepository`. The word `Mapper` have different meaning in `DAL`.

Comment: So should I rename it? How is different between repository and mapper ? :/ I am lost in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) Pattern.

In general: For every table in your db you have an entity and a Dao class for the entity also a database class which communicates with the database.

For example Person, PersonDao, Database.

The person is the entity.
PersonDao uses Database class to query database only for person table.
Database is a CRUD class for the database.